# Error while moving component from application to a library

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-cli

I am having troubles while creating a library of components in top of Vuetify 2.x.

I have created a simple navigation-drawer wrapper:

```html
<template>
    <v-navigation-drawer app v-model="drawer">
        <v-list-item>
            <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title class="title">
                    Application
                </v-list-item-title>
                <v-list-item-subtitle>
                    subtext
                </v-list-item-subtitle>
            </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'MySidebar',
    data: () => ({
        drawer: null,
    }),
};
</script>
```

When this component is placed inside my application, it works as expected. However, when the same component is on a library, the application crashes.

```html
<template>
    <v-app>
        <my-sidebar/>
    </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import MySidebar from 'my-library/src/components/MySidebar.vue'; // Error
import MySidebar from './src/components/MySidebar.vue'; // Works

export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {
        MySidebar,
    },
};
</script>
```

On the first import, the application fails to get the `this.$vuetify` object, but when I `console.log(this.$vuetify)`, it is there.

Some of the console messages:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'breakpoint' of undefined
    at VueComponent.isMobile (VNavigationDrawer.ts?6ca0:193)
    at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js?f9ee:4473)
    ...

[Vue warn]: Error in getter for watcher "isMobile": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'breakpoint' of undefined"

found in

---> <VNavigationDrawer>
       <MySidebar> at my-library/src/components/MySidebar.vue
         <VApp>
           <App> at src/App.vue
             <Root>
...

TypeError: Cannot read property 'breakpoint' of undefined
    at VueComponent.isMobile (VNavigationDrawer.ts?6ca0:193)
    at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js?f9ee:4473)
    ...

[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'application' of undefined"

found in

---> <VNavigationDrawer>
       <MySidebar> at my-library/src/components/MySidebar.vue
         <VApp>
           <App> at src/App.vue
             <Root>
```

**Additional Information:**

- My Library has vuetify as dev dependency for development proposes
- I am using the library via `npm link`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some help from the Vuetify team, I found out that the problem was that Webpack was using Vuetify from the library instead of using from the app. This was caused by the use of `npm link` on my-app to use my-library together with Vuetify installed as dev-dependency on my-library.

Some possible solutions:

- On my-library, use `npm install --only=prod` instead of `npm install`. This will prevent the conflict by not installing Vuetify on the library.
- On my-app, add the following lines to `vue.config.js`:

  ```js
  const path = require('path');

  module.exports = {
      publicPath: process.env.VUE_APP_PUBLIC_PATH,
      configureWebpack: {
          resolve: {
              alias: {
                  /* Use vuetify from my-app, not from my-library */
                  vuetify: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/vuetify'),
              },
          },
      },
  };
  ```

  This will tell explicitly to Webpack to chose the Vuetify installation from my-app.

Other solutions that did not fit my requirements:

- Stop using `npm link`
- Do not install Vuetify on my-library, install it only on my-app

Comment: Adding `vue: path.resolve('./node_modules/vue')` as an alias to vue.config.js of the parent app solved the problem in my case. I referenced the child library as a local file dependency in package.json of the parent app.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and solved it by deleting the node_modules folder in the component library folder (i.e. `rm -rf my-library/node_modules` in your case).

Comment: Hello Jack, thank you for reminding me of this issue. I posted an answer with 4 possible solutions for this problem.